# Replace html tag inside a string but keep text and re-wrap with custom tag

Tags: jquery, replace, innerhtml, replacewith

i know how to use replace & replaceWith but I need to do something different.

**Example string:**

```
<span class="highlight_grey">example:</span> some additional text   
& <span class="highlight_grey">again...</span> and to wrap up some 
regular <span>span.. no class here</span>
```

**Desired result:**

```
[highlight color="default"]example:[/highlight] some additional text   
& [highlight color="default"]again...[/highlight] and to wrap up some   
regular <span>span.. no class here</span>
```

`element.replace` doesn't work here because I need to replace the entire wrap and keep the text.
`replaceWith` also doesn't help me because I need to use the string and again I am replacing
the wrapping element.

Would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: sorry, I haven't noticed the rest of the string. anyway:

http://jsfiddle.net/WJTb7/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
<span class="highlight_grey">example:</span> some additional text & <span class="highlight_grey">again...</span>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
var oldHtml = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML,
    newHtml;

newHtml = oldHtml.replace(/<span class="highlight_grey">(.*?)<\/span>/gi, '[highlight color="default"]$1[/highlight]')

alert(newHtml);
```

Comment: In the second replace you are replacing unrelated closing span tags... scroll the example (maybe i should break that into lines?).. i need to target only the desired span... thats why i wrote "keep the inner text".. thanks for you help anyway mate.

Comment: sorry, I haven't noticed the rest of your input :) now it's fixed.

Comment: That works beautifully! thanks a lot... going to learn about using "(.*?)" as variables (how is that called? got a time saving tip?). Thanks a lot in anycase.

Comment: it's a regexp - regular expression. I suggest using http://gskinner.com/RegExr :)

Answer (score 1):

this example seems heavy handed and I bet it can be reduced to a more prett'ified version.
Lordex's is a bit more streamlined. I capture the the spans. probably don't need to.

```
// of course, for txt - you'd just use document.getElementById('test').innerHTML,
var txt = '<span class="highlight_grey">example:</span> some additional text & <span class="highlight_grey">again...</span><span> .. MORE SPAN TEXT </span>'


 txt.replace(/(\<span class="highlight_grey"\>)(.*?)(\<\/span>)/g,function(_,$1,$2,$3){ return '[highlight color="default"]' + $2 + '[/highlight]';
```

})

```
// output
// "[highlight color="default"]example:[/highlight] some additional text & [highlight color="default"]again...[/highlight]<span> .. MORE SPAN TEXT </span>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, That other guy was first to come  ;) but thanks i apreaciate it.